# Catch Mouse events on unfocusable controls

Tags: winforms

I have a text box that has the focus and I want to know when the user clicked any unfocusable controls within the dialog. I cannot use textBox.Validating because this event does not fire taking in consideration that the focus will remain on the text box when clicking with the mouse an unfocusable control

Answer (score 1):

Not really understand what you mean by unfocusable controls? Labels?
In any case, you can subscribe to Click or MouseClick event on yours "unfocusable controls".